# css scroll keep appearing though I increase the height

Tags: html, css

This is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAueQ/

There's always a scrollbar on the `campaignDiv` div. I increased the height, but the scrollbar still appears.

[image]

I don't want to use overflow: hidden.

Comment: ah... where's the fiddle...? where's the code...?

Comment: @TJ http://jsfiddle.net/LAueQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `overflow: auto;` on the `ul` which is not as tall as `#campaignDiv`

You should make the `ul` fill the height of its parent by adding:

```
#campaignDiv ul {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAueQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

> though I increase the height but still the scroll appears

this doesn't seems to happen. if you give a greater height the scrollbar disappears.

```
#campaignDiv ul {
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left:5px;
    height:500px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/LAueQ/1/)

removing `overflow: auto;` on the `ul` will also hide it...

Comment: +1 to you but there is another guy answerwed first. sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put an attribute `scrolling="no"`

Comment: +1 to your efforts but sorry someone answered better